# image path from sqlite is not working

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm practicing how to parse XML data and store it into the sqlite. I have done parsing and storing successfully. But I have one problem with displaying image from an url. The URL is formed by combining two NSStrings. One for the fixed address(which I set value) and other based on the name of the photo(retrieved from Sqlite). I am able to create complete URL by retrieving name of photo from Sqlite. But strange thing happen when I use that URL to display image in UIImageView. It does not work. After some testing, I found out there is something wrong with the portion(photo name) I retrieved from Sqlite. If I combine the fixed address with literal name of the photo, it works. Can somebody explain why it happens like this. Thanks in advance.

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"user.db"];
FMDatabase * database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:defaultDBPath];
[database open];



results=[database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM plant WHERE name=?",self.plantname];
while([results next]) {

    name = [results stringForColumn:@"name"];
    category = [results stringForColumn:@"category"];
    instructions = [results stringForColumn:@"instructions"];
    price = [results stringForColumn:@"price"];
    photo=[results stringForColumn:@"photo"];
}

NSString * fixedURL = @"http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/";
NSString *url=[fixedURL stringByAppendingString:photo];
NSLog(url);


NSURL * imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

self.plantImageView.image=image;
```

**Edit**

I've edited based on Rob answer. But there are still problems. I put log below. I've already tried to remove white spaces by using [photo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]. But it does not seem to affect.

```
2014-10-15 02:12:39.505 SqlitePractice[9256:286525] url string = 'http:/services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/mona_lavender.jpg'
2014-10-15 02:12:39.506 SqlitePractice[9256:286525] imgURL = (null)
2014-10-15 02:12:39.516 SqlitePractice[9256:286525] sendAsynchronousRequest failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7a78ba50 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7a66b5e0 "unsupported URL", NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

**Edit 2**

The URL seems to be problem after changing from    stringByAppendingString to stringByAppendingPathComponent. But I found out that even without one slash after http: , it works if I change the photo value. And the image is displayed.

```
NSString * fixedURL = @"http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/";
photo=@"bougainvillea.jpg";
NSString *url=[fixedURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:photo];
NSLog(@"url string = '%@'", url);
NSURL * imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSLog(@"imgURL = %@", imgURL);
```

And the log is below,

```
2014-10-15 12:07:56.650 SqlitePractice[9690:308022] url string = 'http:/services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/bougainvillea.jpg'
2014-10-15 12:07:56.651 SqlitePractice[9690:308022] imgURL = http:/services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/bougainvillea.jpg
```

**Edit 3**
I have changed based on Rob's modified answer.

```
NSURL *fixedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/"];
NSURL *url = [fixedURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[photo stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 NSLog(@"image URL = '%@'", url);


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest failed: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    self.plantImageView.image=image;
}];
```

And here is the log message:

```
2014-10-15 13:40:38.977 SqlitePractice[10436:357359] image URL = 'http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/camellia.jpg%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520'
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you updated your question with specific examples of values that work and values that don't work.

Comment: OK,for example, if I run the program, it gives me the log  http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/camellia.jpg. If I try it and past in the browser, it works fine. I don't know what's wrong inside. But the image is not displayed in simulator. So I try to replace the value of photo(NSString) with the name of the photo, (camellia.jpg),in this case. Then program display the related image. You can also check the image directory here, http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/ . You might get idea how I want to display photo

Comment: In the log output the `url string` starts with `http:/` instead of `http://`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @ maddy, @ Rob Please check Edit 2.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what happen to the slashes :D. Right now my app is working if I type in the exact name of photo. But, actually, photo name is supposed to retrieved from sqlite and append it behind the fixedURL. That part is not working yet.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I have added Edit 3. Please check. I think there might be something wrong in photo name.

Comment: Yes, you would appear to have bad data in your database. You could try to write code to try to fix it as you retrieve it, but I bet the problem is in your code that populated the table. If you just NSLog the `photo`, what does it say? Seems like it must be `camellia.jpg%0A%20%20%20%20` (basically the file name followed by new line and four spaces). I did you perhaps parse this out of an XML file? How did you populate this table? If the data is indeed wrong, then post new question showing us how you populated that table (assuming you don't just find the problem yourself after some diagnostics).

Comment: @Rob, Yes, these photo name are extracted from XML and stored into the SQlite. I'll try to test around the inserting portion. Thank you for your advices.

Comment: I asked because it's a not-entirely-uncommon error in XML parsing. If you want to put your parser somewhere (http://gist.github.com, http://pastie.org, http://pastebin.com, etc.) and I can take a look.

Comment: I tried to add my project to github (I have never done it before) and it seems like I did something wrong. My project become blank. lol. I'll rewrite the code and upload it may be next week.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Unrelated to your problem at hand, instead of `stringByAppendingString`, it's generally better to use `URLByAppendingPathComponent` with a NSURL. It takes care of adding any necessary `/` characters for you. Not critical given your example, but it's more robust.

   Also, if the string might have spaces or other characters not permitted in a URL, you might percent escape it, too.

   Thus, you'd do something like:

   ```
   NSURL *fixedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/"];
   NSURL *url = [fixedURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[photo stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```
2. You should `NSLog` the `NSURL` variable and make sure it's not `nil` (e.g. which could be caused if there were some spaces in the `photo` string, for example, unless you percent escape it).

   In your revised question, in which you share the log, the original URL string (before the conversion to the `NSURL`) is being reported as:

   ```
   http:/services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/mona_lavender.jpg
   ```

   That should be:

   ```
   http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/mona_lavender.jpg
   ```
3. If `imgURL` is not `nil`, but `imageData` is, you might want to retrieve the image data in a manner that retrieves the error. For example, you could:

   ```
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL options:0 error:&error];
   if (!imageData) {
       NSLog(@"dataWithContentsOfURL failed: %@", error);
   }
   ```

Bottom line, go through this one line at a time and identify precisely where it is going wrong.

---

As an aside, you generally would want to avoid using `dataWithContentsOfURL`, but instead use an asynchronous method:

```
NSURL *fixedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/"];
NSURL *url = [fixedURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[photo stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NRURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest failed: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    self.plantImageView.image=image;
}];
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, but there are still problems. I have updated my question with new log created by you. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that UIIMAGEVIEW  will not display Url as image path. I would sugest to try with UIWebView which would display web content (image or whole web page). This example is writen in objective-c.

```
self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES ; 
[self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/mona_lavender.jpg"]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[self.myWebView loadRequest:request]
```